# Position:fixed; in android it is broken, not working,why?

Tags: android, html, css

On desktop it works but on Android as if taking the `position: absolute` or nothing or I don't know.

This is my code:

```
#only_900{
     display: block !important;
    position: fixed;
   bottom: 73px !important;
   z-index: 999;
   width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  --backface-visibility: hidden !important;
  --webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 }

 #grid1wrap{
    --webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important;
    --backface-visibility: hidden !important;
    display: block !important;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 73px !important;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    --webkit-transform: translateZ(0); 
   }
```

Comment: plz share html as well as if possible fiddle example to debug.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3f9vnx3z/ yeah but it is more  dificult and advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this problem is because of the way the various browsers interpret the code. I think that new browsers only make the html as big as the content inside, therefor the HTML and body are not reaching the bottom. Try adding the following CSS code.

```css
html, 
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I try this but nothing, on android div take the position :absolute i think.

Comment: I call add  and remove the class with jquery,he is probably the problem ?

Comment: What happens when there is no jquery running on it? have you tried having is as display inline?

Comment: Yeah a try this but nothing, always the same thing.